# How to pass a GlobalKey through Stateless Widget Children

Tags: flutter, dart, global-variables

I'm trying to create a custom menu bar in my app. Right now, the biggest issue I'm having is passing a state for when it's expanded to it's children after a setState occurs.

I thought about inheritance, but from what I've tried all inheritance needs to be in-line. I can't create a widget where the children [] are fed into the constructor on an ad-hoc basis.

My current approach is to use a GlobalKey to update the State of the children widgets being inserted into the StateFul while updating them directly.

The children for my MenuBar are declared as:

```
  List<MenuBarItem> menuItems;
```

MenuBarItem is an abstract interface class that I intend to use to limit the widgets that can be fed in as menuItems to my MenuBar.

```
abstract class iMenuItem extends Widget{}
```

```
class MenuBarItem extends StatefulWidget implements iMenuItem{
```

At some iterations of this script, I had a bool isExpanded as part of the iMenuItem, but determined it not necessary.

Here is my code at its current iteration:

My Main:

```
void main() {
//  runApp(MainApp());
  //runApp(InherApp());
  runApp(MenuBarApp());
}


class MenuBarApp extends StatelessWidget{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MenuBar(
          menuItems: [
            // This one does NOT work and is where I'm trying to get the 
            // value to update after a setState
            MenuBarItem(
              myText: 'Outsider',
            ),
          ],
        ),

      ),

    );
  }
}
```

My Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';



/// Primary widget to be used in the main()
class MenuBar extends StatefulWidget{

  List<MenuBarItem> menuItems;

  MenuBar({
    required this.menuItems,
  });

  @override
  State<MenuBar> createState() => MenuBarState();

}

class MenuBarState extends State<MenuBar>{

  bool isExpanded = false;
  late GlobalKey<MenuBarContainerState> menuBarContainerStateKey;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    menuBarContainerStateKey = GlobalKey();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
      return MenuBarContainer(
          menuItems: widget.menuItems,
      );

  }

}


class MenuBarContainer extends StatefulWidget{

  List<MenuBarItem> menuItems;
  late Key key;
  MenuBarContainer({
    required this.menuItems,
        key,
  }):super(key: key);

  @override
  MenuBarContainerState createState() => MenuBarContainerState();

}

class MenuBarContainerState extends State<MenuBarContainer>{

  bool isExpanded =  false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    isExpanded = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){


    List<Widget> myChildren = [
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: (){
          setState((){
            this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded;
          });
        },
        child: Text('Push Me'),
      ),
      // This one works. No surprise since it's in-line
      MenuBarItem(isExpanded: this.isExpanded, myText: 'Built In'),
    ];

    myChildren.addAll(widget.menuItems);

    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: myChildren,
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// The item that will appear as a child of MenuBar
/// Uses the iMenuItem to limit the children to those sharing
/// the iMenuItem abstract/interface
class MenuBarItem extends StatefulWidget implements iMenuItem{

  bool isExpanded;
  String myText;
  MenuBarItem({
    key,
    this.isExpanded = false,
    required this.myText,

  }):super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MenuBarItem> createState() => MenuBarItemState();

}

class MenuBarItemState extends State<MenuBarItem>{


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    GlobalKey<MenuBarState> _menuBarState;

    return Row(
      children: <Widget> [
        Text('Current Status:\t${widget.isExpanded}'),
        Text('MenuBarState GlobalKey:\t${GlobalKey<MenuBarState>().currentState?.isExpanded ?? false}'),
        Text(widget.myText),
      ],
    );
  }
}

/// To give a shared class to any children that might be used by MenuBar
abstract class iMenuItem extends Widget{

}
```

I've spent 3 days on this, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `ChangeNotifier`, `ChangeNotifierProvider`, `Consumer` and `context.read` to manage state. You have to add [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) and this import: `import 'package:provider/provider.dart';`. The steps:

1. Set up a `ChangeNotifier` holding `isExpanded` value, with a setter that notifies listeners:

```
class MyNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isExpanded = false;
  bool get isExpanded => _isExpanded;
  set isExpanded(bool isExpanded) {
    _isExpanded = isExpanded;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

2. Insert the above as a `ChangeNotifierProvider` in your widget tree at `MenuBar`:

```
class MenuBarState extends State<MenuBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => MyNotifier(),
        child: MenuBarContainer(
          menuItems: widget.menuItems,
        ));
  }
}
```

After this you can easily read and write the `isExpanded` value from anywhere in your widget tree under the `ChangeNotifierProvider`, for example:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      final myNotifier = context.read<MyNotifier>();
      myNotifier.isExpanded = !myNotifier.isExpanded;
    });
  },
  child: Text('Push Me'),
),
```

And if you want to use this state to automatically build something when `isExpanded` is changed, use `Consumer`, which will be notified automatically upon every change, for example:

```
class MenuBarItemState extends State<MenuBarItem> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<MyNotifier>(builder: (context, myNotifier, child) {
      return Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Current Status:\t${myNotifier.isExpanded}'),
          Text(widget.myText),
        ],
      );
    });
  }
}
```